# How to plot histograms on a 3D plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I have collected data on an experiment, where I am looking at property A over time, and then making a histogram of property A at a given condition B. Now the deal is that A is collected over an array of B values.
So I have a histogram that corresponds to `B=B1, B=B2, ..., B=Bn`. What I want to do, is construct a 3D plot, with the z axis being for property B, and the x axis being property A, and y axis being counts.

As an example, I want the plot to look like this (B corresponds to Temperature, A corresponds to Rg):

[image]

How do I pull this off on python?

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/mplot3d/hist3d.html#sphx-glr-gallery-mplot3d-hist3d-py

Comment: Looks like a [ridgeplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/kde_ridgeplot.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The python library [**joypy**](https://github.com/leotac/joypy) can plot graphs like this. But I'm not sure if you also want these molecules within your graph.

Here an example:

```
import joypy

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
%matplotlib inline


temp = pd.read_csv("data/daily_temp.csv",comment="%")

labels=[y if y%10==0 else None for y in list(temp.Year.unique())]
fig, axes = joypy.joyplot(temp, by="Year", column="Anomaly", labels=labels, range_style='own', 
                          grid="y", linewidth=1, legend=False, figsize=(6,5),
                          title="Global daily temperature 1880-2014 \n(°C above 1950-80 average)",
                          colormap=cm.autumn_r)
```

**Output:**

[image]

See [this thread](https://deepnote.com/@deepnote/Joyplot-Introduction-RmbhozJJRC6alCu8xcsbHQ) as reference.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Maximilian. My question is, how do I get a z-axis showing the heights of these curves?